# How to apply classifier from one set to another in weka & graph training/testing error

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka, cross-validation, data-science

two part question involving weka.

1) once I train a classifier on a set how do i use that classifier on another set?

2) how do i graph the error rate / learning curve in weka?

As of right now I am using the explorer tool (GUI).  I have split my dataset into a training / testing split (60/40).  Run a 10 fold cross validation on my training set and now need to apply this to the testing set.

However, I have no idea how to apply my newly created classifier to the second set nor where to find my training / testing error data to graph.

Comment: Why do you apply 10 fold cross validation on your training set, if you have a test set, where you can evaulate your model? When you have a training and test set, only train your ML model on your test set, and than evaulte it on your test set. 

If you don`t have any test set, apply 10 fold cross validation.